# How to build ios app with Flet(Flutter - Python)?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, flet

I wanted to try Flet (Flutter package for Python)
to test how to build iOS app. But i have encounter this error :

```
Failed to build iOS app

Error (Xcode): lib/main.dart43: Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget? 
Function(CreateControlArgs)>?'.

Encountered error while archiving for device.

Error building Flet app - see the log of failed command above.
```

Simple step to reproduce :

```
> flet create myapp
```

```
> cd myapp
```

```
> flet build ipa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by a contributor.

Github issue :
https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/issues/2646